# How to display a default category from a Joomla component list?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Hi I hope this is a simple problem for someone to solve, where I have in my code:

```
 <?php echo $this->lists['cats']; ?>
```

This will list all the categories available from my JoomGallery category table... I want to select a default category within this i.e. 'users' so when users access the front page the category 'users' will already be in the drop down box. How can I edit the code to do this?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: We might need some, you know, context... like what object is $this what is the code like where you want to use it... basic stuff like that.

Comment: It is vague, but in fairness, $this->lists is quite prevalent in joomla components for creating listboxes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's using option.list or genericlist, but [this link](http://www.ericgoldman.name/web-development/4-joomla/31-how-to-make-drop-down-boxes-select-elements-with-jhtml) will show you how you set the defaults for either.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around it was simply changing the value in this:

```
 $lists['cats'] = JHTML::_('joomselect.categorylist', 1, 'catid', null, null, '- ', null, 'joom.upload');
```

Thx @GDP for pointing me in right direction

Eddie